# 'Embed' cocos2D in UIKit app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I've already created an iPhone app using UIKit. However, for one part of my app i will need to perform relatively heavy graphica (particles, lots of moving images). I can't rewrite the entire app in cocos2D due to my deadline. It's just for graphical purposes and i won't need user input via cocos2D. Another option i was considering was using plain openGL, but i'm quite sure cocos2D will be easier to learn.

In short: How can i use cocos2D in a small part (say one UIView) of my app without rewriting it? (User interaction is not necessary).

Edit: I found out, after a while more searching. For the record if someone else will need it in the future:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/4708

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/9239

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, integrate cocos2d into your project.

1. Copy cocos2d directory into your project from downloaded cocos2d-iphone.
2. Modify cocos2d/ccConfig.h, #define CC_FONT_LABEL_SUPPORT 0
3. Copy fps_images.png into your project from downloaded cocos2d-iphone/Resources/Fonts if you want to show FPS that is implemented in cocos2d.

Next, implement to use cocos2d as [cocos2d-iphone/tests/attachDemo/attachDemo.m](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/master/tests/attachDemo/attachDemo.m).

Comment: Isn't that simply for any cocos2d project? I thought that wouldn't work with an existing UIKit project if you only wanted it in one UIView?

Comment: attachDemo is a project that you want, though there are no out-of-the-box projects that are able to import easily into existing UIKit project as far as I know. You can reduce code from attachDemo.m, such like in application delegate methods.